# Simplify exponential expression inside Function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Knowing `C[1] \[Element] Integers` I try to simplify the expression

```
sol={a -> Function[{x}, -Log[1/k[1] - E^(x k[1] + (k[1] (2 I \[Pi] C[1]))/k[1])/k[1]]]}
```

expecting result `{a -> Function[{x}, -Log[1/k[1] - E^(x k[1])/k[1]]]}`

Obvious attempt

```
Simplify[sol,C[1] \[Element] Integers]
```

doesn't simplify.

Cumbersome workaround

```
Log[ Simplify[Exp[a[x]] /. sol, C[1] \[Element] Integers]]
(* Log[k[1]/(1 - E^(x k[1]))] *)
```

gives the expected result.

My question:

Is there a more direct way to simplify the rule `sol`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying procedures never touch function bodies, Mapping does not work immediately but delayed

```
MapAt[(PowerExpand[FullSimplify[#]] &),Function[{x}, -Log[
1/k[1] - E^(x k[1] + (k[1] (2 I \[Pi] C[1]))/k[1])/k[1]]] , {2}]

 Function[{x}, (PowerExpand[FullSimplify[#1]] &)[-Log[
1/k[1] - E^(x k[1] + (k[1] (2 I \[Pi] C[1]))/k[1])/k[1]]]]
```

You have to expose the kernel to Simplify.

```
Function[{x}, 
-Log[1/k[1] - E^(x k[1] + (k[1] (2 I \[Pi] C[1]))/k[1])/k[1]]] /.
{Function[a_, b_] :> Function @@ PowerExpand[FullSimplify[{a, b}]]}

   Function[{x}, -I \[Pi] - Log[-1 + E^(2 I \[Pi] C[1] + x k[1])] + Log[k[1]]]
```

Comment: Thanks ! `sol /.
 {Function[{a_}, b_ ] :> 
   Apply[Function, {a , 
     FullSimplify[ b , C[1] \[Element] Integers]  }] }` seems to answer my question . But there is an error message "Function::flpar: Parameter specification {a_} in Function[{a_},b_] should be a symbol or a list of symbols." which I would like to remove.

Answer (score 3):

My attempt:

```
sol /. {Rule[s1_, s2_]} :> List@Rule[s1, Function @@ {Part[s2, 1], Simplify[Part[s2, 2], C[1] ∈ Integers]}]

(*{a -> Function[{x}, -Log[-((-1 + E^(x k[1]))/k[1])]]}*)
```

Also:

```
sol /. {Rule[s1_, s2_]} :> DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction[Simplify[{Rule[Apply[s1, Part[s2, 1]], Part[s2, 2]]}, C[1] ∈ Integers]]

(*{a -> Function[{x}, -Log[-((-1 + E^(x k[1]))/k[1])]]}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for these two interesting alternatives

Comment: This makes me think of something for the function repository. Regards, Ulrich!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = {a -> Function[{x}, -Log[
       1/k[1] - E^(x k[1] + (k[1] (2 I π C[1]))/k[1])/k[1]]]};

ReplacePart[sol, {1, -1, 2} -> 
  Simplify[sol[[1, -1, 2]], C[1] ∈ Integers]]

(* {a -> Function[{x}, -Log[-((-1 + E^(x k[1]))/k[1])]]} *)
```